# Issue creating new GRAILS project in IntellijIdea

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, installation

I am new to Grails. I downloaded grails from [this site](https://grails.org/downloads). Unzipped the file in some location and configured GRAILS_HOME and windows Path variables.

Then I installed Ingellij Idea and trying to create a new grails project using [this link](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Grails_application_with_IntelliJ_IDEA). But the problem is that, project-structure of the newly created project is not the same as grails-projct. And also, it let me not to create any controller/domain-class/view at all.

Anybody, any idea? Is my installation process wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have `Ultimate Edition`, to change the view click on view->Tool windows->Grails view

Comment: Hi Alidad, thanks for your answer. But the problem is, in view->Tool windows, there is no option "Grails view" in my IDE.

Comment: Are you using a paid license or free trial of Ultimate Edition?

Comment: it is paid licence of ultimate edition.

Comment: Dear concern,

finally my problem is solved. The problem was jdk version. My installed jdk version was 1.7 update 25. I changed it to jdk 1.7 update 45 and the problem gone.